# How to do string search in python much faster?

Tags: python-3.x, string, twitter, tweets

I have list of tweets and list of keywords. I have to search for keywords in each tweet and assign 1 if there is at least one of the keywords in the tweet otherwise 0. I have written the following code for it.

```
features = []
  for tweet in tweets_list:
    check=0
    for key in key_list:
      if re.search(r'\b'+re.escape(key)+r'\b', tweet.lower()):
        features.append(1)
        check=1
        break
    if check==0:
      features.append(0)
```

The above code is working, but it is taking of lot of time, as the number of keywords is around 12k and the number of tweets is around 30k.
I couldn't figure out how to write optimized code for this.

Comment: just using  `if x in str` is quite fast on it's own, and should be faster than using regular-expression in most cases. Could you give some examples of some tweets and the sub-strings that should be matched?

Comment: I can't use `if x in str` as x may be a subword in the tweet and I want to look for only words.

Comment: Then please update your question with that, so that we know what limitations we're looking at. Please give us examples of what you just explained as well. ; The only time you can be too verbose is if your Significant Other asks you if they look fat.